# Use function parameter in multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, rust

## EDIT - Got solution working with "Crossbeam"

My solution:

```rust
use crossbeam::thread;
fn analyze_string(contents: String) -> u64 {
    let splitted_contents = contents.split("\n").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    thread::scope(|s| {
        let oxygen_thread = s.spawn(|_| {
            let mut oxygen = splitted_contents.clone();
            let mut n = 0;
            while oxygen.len() > 1 {
                if oxygen.len() > 1 {
                    let (z, o) = get_ratings_of_bits(&oxygen, n);
                    if z > o {
                        oxygen.retain(create_predicate('0', n));
                    } else if o > z {
                        oxygen.retain(create_predicate('1', n)); 
                    } else if o == z {
                        oxygen.retain(create_predicate('1', n));
                    }
                }
                n += 1;
            }
            oxygen.get(0).unwrap().clone()
        });
        let co2_thread = s.spawn(|_| {
            let mut co2 = splitted_contents.clone();
            let mut n = 0;
            while co2.len() > 1 {
                if co2.len() > 1 {
                    let (z, o) = get_ratings_of_bits(&co2, n);
                    if z > o {
                        co2.retain(create_predicate('1', n));
                    } else if o > z {
                        co2.retain(create_predicate('0', n));
                    } else if o == z {
                        co2.retain(create_predicate('0', n));
                    }
                }
                n += 1;
            }
            co2.get(0).unwrap().clone()
        });
        let oxygen_decimal = isize::from_str_radix(oxygen_thread.join().unwrap(), 2).unwrap();
        let co2_decimal = isize::from_str_radix(co2_thread.join().unwrap(), 2).unwrap();
        (oxygen_decimal * co2_decimal).try_into().unwrap()
    }).unwrap()
}
```

I have a function that looks like this:

```rust
fn create_threads_and_handle_data(inputs: String) {
   let splitted_inputs = inputs.split("\n").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
}
```

I want to use my variable `splitted_inputs` in two different threads (because I want to speed this up a bit). So I am creating a thread like this:

```rust
fn create_threads_and_handle_data(inputs: String) {
  let splitted_inputs = inputs.split("\n").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
  let thread1 = thread::spawn(move || {
    let mut copied: Vec<&str> = splitted_inputs.clone();
    // Some irrelevant handling the copied vector
    return copied.get(1).unwrap().clone();
  )};
  let thread2 = thread::spawn(move || {
    let mut copied: Vec<&str> = splitted_inputs.clone();
    // Some irrelevant handling the copied vector
    return copied.get(0).unwrap().clone();
  )};

  let thread1_value = thread1.join().unwrap();
  let thread2_value = thread2.join().unwrap();
}
```

Now I am getting an error that says `"contents" does not live long enough. borrowed value does not live long enough`

How do I alter this code so I can use the argument in my threads?

Comment: Crossbeam's [scoped threads](https://docs.rs/crossbeam/0.8.1/crossbeam/fn.scope.html) are just what the doctor ordered.

Comment: Yes! Looks like Crossbeam did it. I will edit this answer with the a solution using Crossbeam. Thanks for the recommendation

Comment: Could you post that as an answer, and give yourself the checkmark?